# Ionic Cordova QrScanner layout inconsistency?

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, layout

I am having layout inconsistencies with my layout for the qrscanner.  The Qrcode on iOS and web view looks normal, however, on android it comes off abit wonky, (not centered).

Here's a screenshot on Android:
[image: Android Layout]

And here's a screenshot on iOS:

[image: iOS layout]

and here's my ionic/angular code:

```
<ion-card-content class="qr-canvas">

    <qrcode
            style=" justify-content: center;"
            [qrdata]="qrCode"
            [size]="300"
            [level]="'Q'"
            colorlight="#e9ecef"
            *ngIf="qrCode!==''">
    </qrcode>


    <ion-button expand="block" (click)="copyToClipboard()" [disabled]="!isEmpty">
        <ion-icon name="copy" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        Copy to clipboard
    </ion-button>

    <ion-item>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            This address can be used for any
        </p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-card-content>
```

and the scss:

```
.wrap-qr-code {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ion-card-content {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.qr-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00AAC8;
}
```

What could I do to resolve this?  Thank you-

Elias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it..

I passed a two-way binding for the [size] property as such,

> ```
> <qrcode
>       [qrdata]="qrCode" 
>       [size]="canvasSize" <!-- passed it a canvasSize property in the .ts (public canvasSize = 0;) -->
>       [level]="'Q'" 
>       colorlight="#e9ecef" 
>       colorDark="#000000"
>       *ngIf="qrCode!==''">
> </qrcode>
> ```

I then get the window size of the phone and minus 50 from the original size.. pretty odd but it works..

> ionViewWillEnter() {
>       this.canvasSize = window.screen.width - 50;
>
> ```
> console.log("Canvas size: " + this.canvasSize);
> ```
>
> }